# Pythonic way of writing multiple functions?

Tags: python, function, syntax, format, newline

I've been writing Python code for roughly 3-4 months now. I usually write in Atom but recently decided to try out PyCharm after seeing many good things about it. While writing some functions, I noticed I was getting errors and I didn't know why. According to PyCharm, functions should have two newlines after them?

I'd never seen this, or at least never noticed it before. I decided to Google some sample Python code and some pictures showed code with two newlines, but some only had one. Is there a generally accepted way of going about this or is it down to user preference?

Comment: You only *need* an extra newline if the function doesn't end with a `return`. I always use one anyway just to be consistent and to provide visual separation. Edit: and of course I missed the fact that you were asking about *two* blank lines.

Comment: It looks like it's not necessary, but recommended by PEP8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466860/expected-two-blank-lines-pep8-warning-in-python

Comment: Many of the "errors" that IDEs like PyCharm report are not really errors, but programming guidelines.

Comment: Also, I won't be giving you error (marked as red) but a suggestion instead (marked as yellow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is considered as a good practice. As per [PEP-0008 document](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines):

> Surround top-level function and class definitions with two blank lines.
>
> Method definitions inside a class are surrounded by a single blank line.
>
> Extra blank lines may be used (sparingly) to separate groups of related functions. Blank lines may be omitted between a bunch of related one-liners (e.g. a set of dummy implementations).
>
> Use blank lines in functions, sparingly, to indicate logical sections.

PEP-8 is a *Style Guide for Python Code*