# Printing the results of my function

Tags: python

Its a very noob question, I am trying my hands on python and going through [this](https://www.practicepython.org/exercise/2014/02/05/02-odd-or-even.html) exercise right now. Their solution suggests it could actually be done without creating any function which makes it easier, however, I am still wondering why my function wouldn't work.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    1 number = int(input("Please enter a number of your choice: "))
CC  2 def odd_or_even():
    3     if number % 2 == 0:
    4         print("You've entered an Even number :)")
    5     else:
    6         print("You've enterd an Odd number.")
    7
    8     return odd_or_even()
```

Also, you'll notice I have a warning on second line which reads:

```
oddOrEven.py|2 col 1 C| E302 expected 2 blank lines, found 0 [pep8]
```

in my vim. Can someone explain what exactly's wrong there?

Comment: Your function recurses infinitely.

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing "return" and simply calling "odd_or_even()". Is that the ideal solution?

Comment: @Nishant: Far from ideal; for example, it should take `number` as a parameter, as opposed to using a global variable.

Comment: Can I add code in comments? I removed the global variable and made it look like "odd_or_even(int(input("Please enter a number of your choice: "))) ". Is that what you were referring to @Scott

Comment: Look at @HunterM267's answer.

Comment: It's better to ask a new question—changing the code in an already posted question (as a result of other's comments) generally is not a good idea because it changes the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st:** I would write your function definition above the code that calls it.
**2nd:** In line 8, the statement: return odd_or_even() makes it a recursive function. It can be fixed by removing the call to your function.

#### Like this:

```
def odd_or_even(number):
     if number % 2 == 0:
          print("You've entered an Even number :)")
     else:
          print("You've enterd an Odd number.")
     return 

number = int(input("Please enter a number of your choice: "))
odd_or_even(number)
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function `odd_or_even` calls itself at the last line, which means it will never return anything.
2. That hasn't caused a problem (yet), because you never call `odd_or_even` from anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `number` variable into your `odd_or_even` function. You may also want to call the function.

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number of your choice: "))   
odd_or_even(number) #call function with number variable

def odd_or_even(number):   #define function and pass number parameter                                                       
   if number % 2 == 0:                                                         
      print("You've entered an Even number :)")                               
   else:                                                                       
      print("You've enterd an Odd number.")                                                                                                           
   return #end function
```

[expected two blank lines pep8 warning in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33466860/expected-two-blank-lines-pep8-warning-in-python) should answer your question relating to line 2.